# Why does emoji have two different utf-8 codes? How to convert emoji from utf-8 , use NSString in ios?

Tags: ios, unicode, utf-8, nsstring, emoji

We have found an issue, that some emoji have two utf-8 codes, such as:

```
emoji   unicode    utf-8                another utf-8
      U+1F601    \xf0\x9f\x98\x81     \xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb8\x81
```

But ios language can't decode the other type of utf-8, so resulting an error when i decode string from utf-8.

[image: ios code]

---

In all documents i found, i can just find one type of utf-8 code for a emoji, no where to find the other.

Documents i referenced includes:

[emoji code link](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode#)

[whole utf-8 code link](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl)

But in a web tool [bianma](http://bianma.911cha.com/), all the two types of utf-8 code can be converted into emoji correctly.

[image: input code]

[image: ouput]

---

So, my question is :

1. Why does there have two types of utf-8 codes for one emoji ?
2. Where has a document which includes the two types of utf-8 codes?
3. How to correctly convert string from utf-8, using NSString in ios language?

Comment: This had me intrigued as my first thought was that the long UTF-8 representation was two UTF-8 blocks. It turns out that there are two variations of UTF-8, **CESU-8 and Modified UTF-8**, which encode UTF-16 style. You may be able to use this article http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/95636-read-write-utf-8-strings-between-iphone-and-java-application-using-sockets.html to write a decoder if there's no suitable iOS/Objective-C native decoder.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack That's the answer I think. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @user692793 Please never post text as images, especially not code or output.

Comment: Thanks @roeland. I think a proper answer should contain some working code, but as I'm not an Objective-C coder I'll leave it to someone else to pickup the glory :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> 0xF0, 0x9F, 0x98, 0x81

Is the correct UTF-8 encoding for U+1F601 .

> 0xED, 0xA0, 0xBD, 0xED, 0xB8, 0x81

Is not a valid UTF-8 sequence(*). It should really be rejected; iOS is correct to do so.

This is a bug in the bianma tool: the `convertUtf8BytesToUnicodeCodePoints` function is more lenient about what input it accepts than the specified algorithm in eg [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#page-5).

This happens to return a working string only because the tool is written in JavaScript. Having decoded the above byte sequence to the bogus surrogate code point sequence U+D83D,U+DE01 it then converts that into a JavaScript string using a direct code-point-to-code-unit mapping giving `\uD83D\xDE01`. As this is the correct way to encode  in a UTF-16 string it appears to have worked.

(*: It *is* a valid CESU-8 sequence, but that encoding is just “bogus broken encoding for compatibility with badly-written historical tools” and should generally be avoided.)

You should not usually encounter a sequence like this; it is typically not worth catering for unless you have a specific source of this kind of malformed data which you don't have the power to get fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer.  We read string data from our server which use C++ language, after server convert unicode string to utf-8, this issue occurs. One more thing need to mention is that, when our client receive data as a string value cstr, and printf("%s", cstr) it's correct. But when convert string to NSString, NSString *ocstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:cstr.c_str() length:cstr.length() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  ocstr results as nil. why apple do not support the CESU-8 sequence? Do we have function to resolve the issue?

Comment: I would first look at the C++ server UTF-8 encoder, to see if it can be fixed properly at source. CESU-8 is considered an undesirable anomaly that you'd never deliberately want to use; most systems don't support it. If you *have* to accept it you'll need to write your own CESU-8 decoder walking through the input byte array (or use an existing library, eg ICU though that would be a really heavy dependency just for this).

Comment: Just as a side note, there is one particularly bothersome source of encoding like this:  JNI (Java Native Interface).  If you attempt to retrieve "UTF-8" bytes from a Java string you will receive the "modified UTF-8" variant.  That is a rather large source of malformed data that cannot be fixed, unfortunately.

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me in php to send a message with emoji to telegram bot:

```
$message_text = " \xf0\x9f\x98\x81 ";
```

Comment: This is just too-off-topic.